# Backend Error for query I'm running for particular monthly file: June

Tags: backend

I've been trying to run this query all night at different occasions and seem to consistently receiving a "Back end Error". It seems all other month's have run (though admittedly some experienced the error so I reran and it worked).

Query is:

```
SELECT 
  raw.c.Country_Name AS Country, 
  ytfin.yt_Channel AS YT_Channel, 
  ytfin.Account AS YT_Account, 
  raw.y.Content_Type AS Content_Type, 
  MIN(ytfin.Novation_Date) AS Novation_Date, 
  AVG(ytfin.Video_Duration_sec) AS Video_Duration_sec, 
  SUM(raw.y.Watch_Page_Views) AS Watch_Page_Views, 
  SUM(raw.y.Embedded_Player_Views) AS Embedded_Player_Views, 
  SUM(raw.y.Total_Earnings) AS Total_Earnings, 
  SUM(raw.y.Gross_YouTube_sold_Revenue) AS Gross_YouTube_sold_Revenue, 
  SUM(raw.y.Gross_Partner_sold_Revenue) AS Gross_Partner_sold_Revenue, 
  SUM(raw.y.Gross_AdSense_sold_Revenue) AS Gross_AdSense_sold_Revenue 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
     y.Video_ID, 
     y.Custom_ID, 
     y.Day, 
     y.Country, 
     c.Country_Name, 
     y.Content_Type, 
     y.Policy, 
     y.Embedded_Player_Views, 
     y.Watch_Page_Views, 
     y.Gross_YouTube_sold_Revenue, 
     y.Gross_Partner_sold_Revenue, 
     y.Gross_AdSense_sold_Revenue, 
     y.Total_Earnings 
   FROM 
     Youtube_Raw_Country.201206_Jun AS y 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     Country_Codes.iso_3166_1_country_codes as c 
     ON y.Country = c.Code) AS raw
INNER JOIN 
  All_YT_Video_IDs.201206_Jun_2012 AS ytfin 
  ON raw.y.Video_ID = ytfin.Video_ID
GROUP BY Country, YT_Channel,YT_Account, Content_Type
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to properly format your questions. Code (including SQL) should be properly indented (a minimum of four spaces), and long lines should be broken by line feeds. Doing so makes your question easier to read, and therefore vastly improves your chances of getting an answer. If you're not sure how to format code, see the help for the text area you're entering it into - there's a `?` button toward the top right corner. (Also, please don't include "thanks" and signatures; if you want people to know who you are, use your profile to introduce yourself.)